# Fetch data from a nested array

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I would like to know if there is a way to get the length from a nested array.

My data is a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "data" :[
        "item1" :'',
        "item2" :[{
            "id" :1,
            "text":'text'
        },{
            "id" :2,
            "text" : 'text 
        }] 
    ]
}
```

I'm using angular 6 and ngx-restangular.
Is possible to get the item 2 length?

Comment: Won’t data.item2.length help?

Comment: You are missing a single-quote at the end of `text` (after id - 2) **and** you can't give items in arrays names (meaning `item1`, `item2`)

Comment: Is this a valid json?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara no this is completely invalid

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is the question does not provide a valid json. A valid json for the same would be like as under :

```
{
    "data": {
        "item1": "",
        "item2": [{
                "id": 1,
                "text": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "text"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now you can fetch the second element size simply by

```
data["item2"].length
```

or

```
data.item2.length
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the Answer from @AurA

If you had to work with a valid array:

```
[
  [ "item0.0", "item0.1" ],
  [ "item1.0", "item1.1" ]
]
```

you could access the length of the nested arrays like this:

```js
let a = [
  ["item0.0", "item0.1"],
  ["item1.0", "item1.1"]
];

let lengthA0 = a[0].length;
let lengthA1 = a[1].length;

console.log("length of a0: ", lengthA0);
console.log("length of a1: ", lengthA1);
```